# Classic ASP - Application stopping with Session data

Tags: session, asp-classic

Im working on some classic ASP functions.

In one wsc file im setting the session like so.

```
Session("ordertype") = "morning"
```

Then in the other wsc file im checking if that exists like so.

```
If Session("ordertype") Is Nothing Then
    ' Do stuff here
End if
```

But everytime it gets to checking if the session exists, the application just stops.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any change if you use `Session.Contents("ordertype")` ?

Comment: `if len(Session("ordertype"))>0 then`. I never used "Is Nothing" in this cases, not sure if there is your mistake.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa You wouldn't because it's a `string` but if it contained an object reference it would.

Answer (score 2):

The `Is` operator is valid but not in the context you are trying to use it.

> **From the VbScript Reference**
>
> > *Compares two object reference variables.*
> >
> > ```vb
> > result = object1 Is object2
> > ```

If you where setting an object reference using the `Set` command then using this kind of comparison would be acceptable.

In this case though your `Session("ordertype")` contains a string which is not an object reference type, instead use a simple `Len()` check to check whether you have assigned a string or not. To avoid Nulls use

```vb
'Check Length of Session value avoid Null by concatenating empty string.
If Len(Session("ordertype") & "") > 0 Then
  'Do Stuff here
End If
```

> **Alternative Method**
>
> You can also use `VarType(Session("ordertype"))` to check your Session variable type first to avoid Nulls as [@ZeeTee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916535/zee-tee) suggests.

Comment: @ZeeTee Where's this db object? `Session("ordertype") = "morning"` That my friend is a `string` nothing more.

Comment: @ZeeTee What are you on about? Just because they have written `If Session("ordertype") Is Nothing Then` doesn't make it right. The value is in the code sample `Session("ordertype") = "morning"` which is a string, I'm lost to where this *"db object"* reference you have plucked out of the air is coming from. The OP doesn't mention dbs, connections or anything like that, it is all assumption on your part.

Comment: Ok, then you can't use `Is Nothing` is the answer since the variable isn't an object.  If you make an edit I will remove my downvote.